# does the result given still hold, if i replaced Darboux sums with Reimann sums?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

Corollary : Let $I=[a,b]$ and let $f$ be bounded on $I$. If $\{P_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is a sequence of partitions of $I$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} U(f;P_n)-L(f;P_n)=0$ then $f$ is integrable and $\lim_{n \to \infty} U(f;P_n) = \int_a^b f(x) \, dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} L(f;P_n)$.

In the given result, I need to understand if i replaced Darboux sums ( upper and lower sums) with Riemann sums in the limit, will the result still hold? and why isn't the converse true? even if i took $S(f;P_n)-S(f;Q_n)$ and as the difference went to zero, would it be an Riemann integrable function?
I think the converse of this result should be true,saying f is integrable allows me to take any difference of sums ( either Riemann or Darboux) and will converge to zero as the mesh of $P_n$ goes to zero. Also if i took Riemann sums instead in the limit for a sequence of partitions, satisfying the condition, then f still is integrable.

Comment: **Riemann**, not Reimann.

Comment: Please don't use pictures.

Comment: Mulaan, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged).

Comment: @DietrichBurde I didn't know pictures are discouraged here. In the end of the day all we as students want is to understand better , if that meant through a picture or typing up a code, It shouldn't really create any problems.

Comment: You misunderstand the point of the result. The point is that if you have *any one* sequence of partitions whose difference between upper and lower sums goes to zero, then you have integrability. What the "standard" definition requires is ostensibly much stronger: that you should say that *any* sequence of partitions with mesh going to zero, with *any* tagging scheme will have its Riemann sums converge and all of them to the same value. This means that if you consider Darboux sums then you get to pick a sequence of partitions at your own convenience without sacrificing generality.

Comment: Also pictures *do* create problems, for example they impede the ability to search (which means answering your question is less useful for someone else with essentially the same question than it would be otherwise).

Comment: Mulaan, I think you will be good in using MathJax, and you already wrote a text. In the end of the day you will get much better responses if you try to help people in understanding your problem. Often they have the feeling, someone just uploads homework and hopes others will do all their work.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I am not really good at using MathJax but I have replaced the picture and wrote the statement instead. I hope this is better now and doesn't give an impression of "leaving my homework for others".

Comment: Very good, after a few trials it will work. You need to place dollar signs around the math terms.

Comment: I put in the MathJax. You can probably examine it and learn how to write several common  math symbols in MathJax/LaTeX.

Comment: @Ian I was about to edit it but thank you.

Comment: By the way, if you are considering a hypothetical equivalent definition of Riemann integration, it is worth checking whether it correctly classifies a function that you know is not Riemann integrable, such as $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R},f(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ 0 & x \not \in \mathbb{Q}\end{cases}$. For example this function is incorrectly classified by the "rule" of "if the left and right hand sums of uniform partitions converge to the same value then the function is Riemann integrable".

Answer (score 1):

What does work is this.  Let $f$ be bounded on $I = [0,1]$.  Let $P_n$ be a sequence of partitions of $I$.  Let $L \in \mathbb R$.
Assume: for every choice $Q_n$ of tags for $P_n$ we have $S(P_n,Q_n,f) \to L$.  Then $f$ is Riemann integrable and $\int_a^b f(x)\;dx = L$.

Explanation of notation:
If $P = \{a=x_0 < x_1 < \dots < x_k = b\}$ is a partition, then a choice of tags for $P$ is a set $Q = \{t_1,t_2,\dots,t_k\}$ such that
$x_{j-1} \le t_j \le x_j$ for all $j$.  Then the corresponding **Riemann sum** is
$$
S(P,Q,f) := \sum_{j=1}^k f(t_j)\;(x_j-x_{j-1})
$$

---

So the point is: for this direction, we must allow all choices of tags.  In the proof that it works, we choose tags with $f(t_j)$ close to
$\sup\{f(x) : x_{j-1} \le x \le x_j\}$ on the one hand, and close to
$\inf\{f(x) : x_{j-1} \le x \le x_j\}$ on the other hand.

For the other direction: if $f$ is Riemann integrable, then for any choice $P_n$ of partitions with norm going to zero, we can take any choice $Q_n$ of tags we like, and conclude $S(P_n,Q_n,f) \to L$.  Convenient choices for $Q$ are: left endpoint; right endpoint; max point; min point.  Another sneaky choice of tags (useful in certain proofs) is the one we get from the mean value theorem,
$$
f(t_j) = \frac{1}{x_{j}-x_{j-1}}\int_{x_{j-1}}^{x_j} f(x)\;dx.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Your corollary is fine and is an easy consequence of the criterion for Riemann integrability :

> **Theorem 1**: A bounded function $f:[a, b] \to\mathbb {R}$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b] $ if and only if for every $\epsilon >0$ there is a corresponding partition $P_{\epsilon} $ of $[a, b] $ such that $U(f, P_{\epsilon}) - L(f, P_{\epsilon}) <\epsilon $.

With some more effort we can prove that:

> **Theorem 2**: A bounded function $f:[a, b] \to\mathbb {R}$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b] $ if and only if for every $\epsilon >0$ there is a corresponding  $\delta>0 $ such that $U(f, P) - L(f, P) <\epsilon $ for every partition $P$ of $[a, b] $ with norm less than $\delta$.

In terms of sequence of partitions you now get the following result based on Theorem 2:

> **Theorem 3**: Let $f:[a, b] \to\mathbb {R} $ be a bounded function and let $\{P_n\} $ be a sequence of partitions of $[a, b] $ such that $||P_n||$, the norm of $P_n$, tends to $0$ as $n\to\infty $. Then $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b] $ if and only if $\lim_{n\to\infty} U(f, P_n) - L(f, P_n) =0$.

For Riemann sums we have the following condition which is similar to Cauchy condition:

> **Theorem 4**: Let $f:[a, b] \to\mathbb {R} $ be a bounded function. Then $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b] $ if and only if for every $\epsilon>0$  there is a corresponding partition $P_{\epsilon} $ of $[a, b] $ such that $|S(f, P), - S(f, Q)|<\epsilon$ for all partitions $P, Q$ of $[a, b] $ with $P_{\epsilon} \subseteq P, P_{\epsilon} \subseteq Q$.

There is a similar criterion for Riemann sums in terms of partition norms:

> **Theorem 5**: Let $f:[a, b] \to\mathbb {R} $ be a bounded function. Then $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b] $ if and only if for every $\epsilon>0$  there is a corresponding $\delta>0$ such that $|S(f, P), - S(f, Q)|<\epsilon$ for all partitions $P, Q$ of $[a, b] $ with norms less than $\delta$.